# What is the background music in The Witcher 3 cinematic launch trailer?

Tags: the-witcher-3, game-music-identification

I was wondering if anybody can name the track played in the background of [*The Witcher 3* cinematic launch trailer?](https://youtu.be/1-l29HlKkXU?t=3m1s)

I do not mean the "Lullaby of Woe" (A Night to Remember) song but the music played in the background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The song playing in the background at the timestamp of your link (it's playing from about 2:05 to 3:20) is ["A Hole in the Sun" by Two Steps From Hell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KG7mgl6v41c).